# Facebook connect - api_client->users_getInfo throws error Cannot use string offset as an array

Tags: facebook

I have this piece of code which works 90% of the time:

```
$user_details=$fb->api_client->users_getInfo($fb_user, array('last_name','first_name','proxied_email'));
$firstName=$user_details[0]['first_name'];
```

But sometimes I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Cannot use string offset as an array for line
$firstName=$user_details[0]['first_name'];
```

I have read several people report the same issue - but I'm still not clear as to what is the reason - Am I getting this error because facebook is not returning any results or am I getting because it is returning only a single array instead of array of arrays.

This is the fix I'm thinking of:

```
if (!is_array($user_details)) {
$firstName='';
}
else
{
$firstName = ($user_details[0]) ? $user_details[0]['first_name'] : $user_details['first_name'];
}
```

Also if I'm not getting the name - is it because of a timeout issue or something else?

Thanks

Comment: i have run into this issue a few times while looking over my error logs. I haven't added more detailed logging to catch it. Just assumed it was due to an invalid fb_id or something. I'll check into it later tonight.

Comment: Gublooo, I'm still waiting for it to happen again; I havent changed anything in that part of the flow. Just wanted to check in a let you know I havent forgotten.

Comment: Thanks - Its very weird - for the same user - I tried it like 30 times and 29 times it worked fine - and it happened only once - so I have no idea how to repeat it - although 2 of my test users have reported this issue to me and when I check their account - facebook has not returned their names...so kind of lost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$user_details=$fb->api_client->users_getInfo($fb_user, array('last_name','first_name','proxied_email'));
            if (!is_array($user_details)) {
                $firstName='';
                $lastName='';
            }
            else
            {
                $firstName = ($user_details[0]) ? $user_details[0]['first_name'] : $user_details['first_name'];
                $lastName = ($user_details[0]) ? $user_details[0]['last_name'] : $user_details['last_name'];
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just modify your `php.ini` and set parameter or add:

```
magic_quotes_gpc = Off
```

Comment: i dont see how that could fix the issue as magic_quotes_gpc is already off.