# PHP error: facebook connect - Cannot use string offset as an array

Tags: php, facebook

This is the error:  `Cannot use string offset as an array in line 41`

line 41 is this :  `$data['first_name'] = $user_details[0]['first_name'];`

this is the code:

```
$user_details = $facebook->api_client->users_getInfo($authData["uid"], 'first_name,last_name,pic_square,email'); 

$data['first_name'] = $user_details[0]['first_name'];
$data['last_name'] = $user_details[0]['last_name']; 
$data['pic'] = $user_details[0]['pic_square']; 
$data['email'] = $user_details[0]['email']; 
$data['uid'] = $user_details[0]['uid']; 
easyRegister($data['uid'],$data['first_name'],$data['last_name'],$data['email'],$data['pic'],1);
```

Comment: do print_r($user_details); and see what you see..

Comment: and see this too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2701995/facebook-connect-api-client-users-getinfo-throws-error-cannot-use-string-offs